# How do I get the checkout fields inside woocommerce_payment_complete action?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I want to trigger sending another custom email with the checkout fields when the order is completed. How do I access the checkout fields inside `woocommerce_payment_complete`?

Or is there some other action I should use?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete','new_email_notification' );
function new_email_notification($order_id) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout = $woocommerce->checkout();
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $myuser_id = (int)$order->user_id;
    $user_info = get_userdata($myuser_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
    ...
```

I'm able to get the order information but not the checkout fields.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a longtime ago, and was probably already solved by OP - but its still what popsup on google - so i will answer it :)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete','new_email_notification' );
function new_email_notification($order_id) 
{
    //$_POST will contain all fields in the form, and is easily accessed by their  form names 
    $aFields = $_POST;
    $sFieldNameYouWant = $aFields['field_name_you_want];
}
```